# Is it possible to pass a method body as a parameter in Java?

Tags: java, android, methods, parameter-passing

I am doing some android programming. I am adding buttons to a view. Each button has its own behaviour for its `onClick` function. But the code seems repetitive. For example:

```
// the view
View v = new View(this);
// first button
Button b1 = new Button(this);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // some method body1
            }
        });
v.addView(b1);

// second button
Button b2 = new Button(this);
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // some method body2
            }
        });
v.addView(b2);

// nth button
// ...
```

Is there a more concise way to add buttons to a view like by passing a method body to a method or some other way? For example like:

```
public void addButton(MethodBody methodBody)
{
   Button b = new Button(this);
   b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                methodBody
            }
        });
   v.addView(b);
}
```

EDIT: So after seeing the suggestions for lambda, is it possible to do something like the below where there is a general method and just take the body as parameter?

```
public void addButton(MethodBody methodBody)
{
   Button b = new Button(this);
   b.setOnClickListener(v -> 
      {
          methodBody
      }
   );
   v.addView(b);
}
```

EDIT 2: I guess we can do this

```
// general method
public void addButton(OnClickListener onClickListener)
{
    Button button = new Button(this);
    // other stuff
    button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    v.addView(button);
}

// run the method
addButton(v -> {
            // some body
        });
```

Comment: [Lambdas](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use **Java 8** Lamdas:

```
b1.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
    // // some method body1
});

b2.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
    // // some method body2
});
```

To enable this in Android Studio add the following code block inside **build.gradle (app)**

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8's [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

```
void onCreate(){
    //...
    findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(this::handleBtn1Click);
    findViewById(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener(this::handleBtn2Click);
    findViewById(R.id.btn3).setOnClickListener(this::handleBtn3Click);
}

void handleBtn1Click(View view){
    // handle btn1 click here
}

void handleBtn2Click(View view){
    // handle btn2 click here
}

void handleBtn3Click(View view){
    // handle btn3 click here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass OnClickListener implementation as parameter, read about [Strategy Design Pattern](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/strategy-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial.html)

Comment: this can be a comment and not an answer.